# Minimize, maximize, close button disappeared

Tags: windows-7

Running a Windows 7 64 bit VMWare 8 guest on a Windows 7 64 bit host.

The buttons disappeared from **all** programs, this is not the case of F11 on IE.

This happens in a virtual VM machine (so probably not an issue of a graphics driver). Other VMs are not affected, nor is the host.

Opening the context menu on the windows' title bar shows Minimze etc, and it's working.

Recent configuration chages - Adobe reader and flash player updated about a week ago. I don't think this could have caused the problem, as I've only noticed it today.

Only suspect: Yesterday the internet was very sluggish, and a support person made me click "Restore advanced settings" in IE. The problem, however, appears in all applications: Office, notepad (see picture below), anything I checked.

[image: Notepad]

Comment: I assume you rebooted the VM?  This seems like a DWM bug so a reboot would usually fix it, I'd expect...

Comment: Thanks, reboot worked! How embarassing. I was so excited by this that I forgot to try rebooting. :-X

Comment: Doh, I figured I was just confirming the obvious.  Posting as an answer, and glad it's fixed.

Comment: Reminds me of a classic "computer support" tale, in which it finally turned out the old woman's computer wasn't turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a DWM bug - usually a reboot is sufficient to fix this sort of problem.